# What's the best solution to keep hidden ID in a table (HTML)

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that shows contacts informations. Each row is a different contact. I'm using JQuery to fire an event when I click some fields of the row. My problem is I need to keep trace of the contact's id but I don't want to show it in a column. So I need each row to be associated to the contact id that it holds without showing it on the screen (like an hidden field).

So what is the best solution to keep trace of that id?

Answer (score 4):

If this is HTML5, use **[data attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)**:

```
<tr data-user-id="2467">...</tr>
```

If it's not, then a common convention is to overload the `id` attribute:

```
<tr id="user_2467">...</tr>
```

Note: you can't do `<tr id="2467">` because **[that's not legal in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2)**:

> **ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter** ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: thanks I was affraid that using the id attribute was bad practice... but it seems not

Comment: @user1229240 As long as the ID is unique, it's not bad practice

Comment: This answer gets my vote because it shows the data attribute option AND the id option (as fallback).

Answer (score 2):

An id attribute.

```
<tr id="contact_12345">
```

Comment: You would need to parse the ID to remove the "contact_" every time you read it.

Comment: @OhCaN Yup. Nothing wrong with that, though; pretty standard! if the first character of the ID is not numeric, you could just store the ID without "contact_" though.

Comment: Even though it's pretty standard, it's a waste when you could put it in an attribute that does support having a numeric first character.

Comment: I agree in general; to me data- attributes are a better option if they're available to you. But your comment implied that you "can't" do it. I also think there's a sane level at which to be concerned about optimization and saving a few characters. Splitting a string with an underscore delimiter is beyond trivial, so it's not something that would concern me in terms of "waste".

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is a `data` attribute. These are valid in HTML5 and can be read using JQuery's `data` function or the standard `attr` function.

```
<tr data-id="345678">
```